# Perl : Split the string into desirable parts

Tags: arrays, regex, string, perl, split

I'm new to perl and trying to split this string into 4 parts and store it in a `@parts` array.

```
$string = " Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043 United States - Map Phone: 650-253-0000 Fax: 650-253-0001 Website: http://www.google.com ";
```

such that `@parts` array should become

```
$part[0]= "Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043 United States - Map" ;
$part[1]= "Phone: 650-253-0000 ";
$part[2]= "Fax: 650-253-0001 ";
$part[3]= "Website: http://www.google.com";
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are there linebreak at the end of every part?

Comment: @Jens No linebreak , it's a continuous string with spaces.

Comment: Are there any eye catcher or what is the logic behind this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split according to the space which exists before one or more non-space characters followed by a colon  which in-turn followed by a space. So this won't match the space which exists before `http:`, since there isn't a space follows `http:` .

```
my $string = "Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043 United States - Map Phone: 650-253-0000 Fax: 650-253-0001 Website: http://www.google.com ";
my @abc = split /\s+(?=[^:\s]+:\s+)/, $string;
print $_, "\n" for @abc;
```

**Output:**

```
Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043 United States - Map
Phone: 650-253-0000
Fax: 650-253-0001
Website: http://www.google.com
```

Comment: I did't understand your regex  why you used `/\s+(?=[^:\s]+:\s+)/` i used  this  `/\s+(?=[\w]+:\s+)/` instead of that . what is the meaning of `[^:\s]` in this case? How the negation works?

Comment: if the key part contain the chars other than `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` then your regex won't work. So i used, `[^\s:]` which matches an char but not of space or colon. `[^:\s]+` one or more times.